# Keep getting 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_pages 400' when using stripe.redirectToCheckout()

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I have this:

```
<script>
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51Gv0ngD3zt5RrIg0XQiKHaK7TOAqzju9yps8jJB2Gch6ksmG4FSnqgyWLv3Qld2EkNHgAb30PLKduYGBuYtZe71A0066dp27DB');
var elements = stripe.elements();
// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
var style = {
    base: {
        // Add your base input styles here. For example:
        fontSize: '16px',
        color: '#32325d',
    },
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {
    hidePostalCode: true, style: style });

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

$(document).on("click", "#subpay", function () {


    stripe
        .redirectToCheckout({
            lineItems: [
                // Replace with the ID of your price
                { price: '1000', quantity: 1 },
            ],
            mode: 'payment',
            successUrl: 'https://your-website.com/success',
            cancelUrl: 'https://your-website.com/canceled',
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
            // error, display the localized error message to your customer
            // using `result.error.message`
            alert(result);
        });

    return false;

})    


</script>
```

And this:

```
 <form id="payment-form">
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="card-element">
                    Credit or debit card
                </label>
                <div id="card-element">
                    <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                </div>

                <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
                <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
            </div>

            <button id="subpay">Submit Payment</button>
        </form>
```

but i get this error in my console:

```
POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_pages 400
```

Im running this under localhost http.

Comment: 400 is the http code for bad request, are you sure you are submitting a payload to the API in a way they expect?

Comment: @BenNelson: Im not sure im new to stripe i need more instructions i find the api reference not good to me at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`price` is the ID of the Price API object, not an amount that you'd like to charge. See here: https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout#stripe_checkout_redirect_to_checkout-options-lineItems-price

Also see the docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client#generate-checkout-button

You set the actual amount to charge on your backend (or dashboard), if you could set it on the client then it would be trivially easy for a malicious user to change the price and pay what they want for whatever it is you're selling.